# Does $C^1$ imply locally Lipschitz on Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions, frechet-derivative

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $\Omega \subseteq X$ open and $f: \Omega \to Y$ continuously (Fréchet-) differentiable. Does this imply that $f$ is already locally Lipschitz? For finite dimensional spaces this is trivially true, but I am not certain if this holds for infinite dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: Yes, you can show it from the definition of differentiability and the fact that the derivative is (uniformly) bounded locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Df_x: X \to Y$ denote the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $x$. Then $Df_x$ is a bounded linear operator (with the operator norm locally uniformly bounded in $x$) such that
$$\lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \frac{\|f(x+h) - f(x) - Df_x(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

In particular, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\|h\|< \delta$ implies that $\|f(x+h) - f(x) - Df_x(h)\| < \|h\|$. As a result, for $\|x-y\| < \delta$,
$$\|f(y) - f(x)\| \leq \|f(y) - f(x) - Df_x(y-x)\| + \|Df_x(y-x)\| < (1+ \|Df_x\|)\|y-x\|$$
which implies that $f$ is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Why is $\| Df_x\|$ locally uniformly bounded in $x$? $C^1$ only implies continuity, but in an infinite dimensional space that's not enough to conclude local boundedness.

Comment: Continuity of $x \mapsto Df_x$ **is** enough to conclude local boundedness. For any fixed $x_0$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $x \in U$ implies that $\|Df_{x_0} - Df_x\| \leq 1$ by continuity. Hence for $x \in U$, $\|Df_x\| \leq \|Df_{x_0}\| + 1$. The use of compactness of closed balls in the finite dimensional case is (a convenient) overkill since continuous functions are locally bounded on any metric space.